# Uno: With a last card power card, are you allowed to play it after you draw a card?

Tags: house-rules, uno

Assuming you play with the following rules:

1. You can't end on a power card (+4, color change)
2. If you can't play and draw a card you are allowed to play it immediatly if that card does match

If you're holding a power card and you draw a card since you can't end on a power card, can you then play the power card instantly (in the same turn like rule 2) since you have 2 cards now?

Comment: Since this question is centered around a house rule I added the house rule tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [these rules](https://www.unorules.com/)

> If the player has no matches or they choose not to play any of their
>   cards even though they might have a match, they must draw a card from
>   the Draw pile. *If that card can be played, play it. Otherwise, the
>   game moves on to the next person in turn.*

You need to play the card you just drew. So you can not use the power card.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that the house rule posed doesn't contradict the other rules, one of which is that it is explicitly illegal to draw a card and then play a card that one could have played. **Drawing a card by choice disallows one the right to play from one's hand later that turn** (and if you weren't drawing by choice, you don't have that right anyway).

---

That said, may I propose a house rule that allows this? If you don't want players to just hoard wild cards to win, one could impose **If one's final card is a wild card, they may play it, but must draw one card so that they still have one card left at the end of their turn** (and as such, must declare "UNO" or be at risk of being caught)".

Comment: Regarding the first part of your post, that is what made it so confusing. There was no card that could have been palyed since it was a power card, but it became playable the second a new card was drawn.

Comment: Except by choosing to draw, playing a card that you didn't just draw is illegal. If you draw a power card, you can play that.

Comment: "If you don't want players to just hoard wild cards to win" ...then use the scoring rules! Hoarding wild cards then becomes a risk, because if your opponent goes out first, that wild card is a huge point penalty for you. Hoard zeroes instead! ;)

Comment: @DanHenderson True. Very rarely does anyone use the actual scoring.